# How to eat barbecue ribs without getting covered in barbecue sauce?

Tags: cleaning, food

I love barbecue ribs but I don't love getting completely covered in barbecue sauce!

I have already tried eating more carefully only using my finger tips but I still get too much barbecue sauce on my face, hands, and fingers.

How can I eat barbecue ribs without getting my hands and face covered in sauce?

Comment: What about your shirt??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With corn cob holders:

[image]

Stick one in the cut bone end and then you'll have a nice little handle.

Comment: He's asking about BBQ ribs...

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 I know, these work the same way for ribs that they do for corn.

Comment: You should edit out the corn picture and say stick them in the ribs.

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 The sentence at the bottom explains usage. I included the corn image for those that weren't familiar with what a corncob holder was. Not to mention that using dinosaur holders for ribs would make for a fun plate presentation.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it was the only answer that basically wasn't "eat differently".

Answer (score 1):

With your fingertips:

[image: fingertips]

It's more exhausting than 'grabbing' the food, but it will keep your hands relatively clean.

Comment: +1. Definitely go with the fingertips. And carefully.

Comment: Is the answer that you can't avoid getting sauce on your hands and face then?

Comment: @MattS. Unless you try eating it with a fork (which is a terrible idea), yes.

Comment: Please see the most recent edit to the questions and edit your answer accordingly. I am looking for solutions that are different from eating differently or more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use just your fingertips: less contact = less sauce on your hands.
2. Use a knife and fork to separate the bone. Use the fork to mount and eat your ribsicle™.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually bones sticking out of the ribs. It may have a little bit of sauce, but the finger-licking is part of the barbecue ribs experience!

[image: Ribs!]
<sub>(source: [tabletalkatlarrys.com](http://www.tabletalkatlarrys.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Barbecue-ribs.jpg))</sub>

Grab one of those with one hand, and then eat off the other end that has meat on it. There should be no sauce on that side. Grab the other side, and there you go! Nom it off. You shouldn't get covered in barbecue sauce.

Comment: "There are usually bones sticking out of the ribs." Like… ribs?